# Solve $a^x + b^x + c^x = 1$ for $x$ when $a, b, c \in (0, 1)$

Tags: exponential-function

I'm looking to solve $a^x + b^x + c^x = 1$ for $x$ when $a, b, c \in [0, 1]$.

If $a+b+c>1$ the solution would be $x>1$, if $a+b+c<1$ then $x < 1$.

A closed formula would be best, but I actually want to do this in JavaScript, so algorithms are also helpful.

Comment: You could use bisection method, or the newton's method

Comment: Oh good point, thanks! I just felt silly doing something numerical when it's possible there is an exact solution. The more I look the less silly a bisection is starting to feel though! For some numbers Wolfram Alpha can solve it exactly, but not for others...

Comment: Forget $x=\infty$, that's not a real number. If $a,b,c\in(0,1)$, there is a unique, positive solution, as the LHS is monotone decreasing from $3$ to $0$. "Exact" is a joke: even something like $\sqrt{2}$ is just a symbol for a numerical approximation.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed it to $a, b, c \in (0, 1)$, it's simpler not to worry about the edge cases.

Comment: For me Newton's method always goes to Infinity in JavaScript.

Comment: I edit my answer to make it more general. I think it is better now.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you look for the positive zero of function
$$f(x)=a^x + b^x + c^x - 1$$ Its first derivative is always negative and the second derivative always positive.

The series expansion around $x=0$ is
$$a^x + b^x + c^x=3+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\log^n(a)+\log^n(b)+\log^n(c)}{n!} x^n$$ Using a few terms and series reversion, we have
$$x=t-\frac{ \log ^2(a)+\log ^2(b)+\log ^2(c)}{2 (\log (a)+\log (b)+\log(c))} t^2+O(t^3)$$ where $t=-\frac {4}{\log(abc)}$.

Let us try with $a=\frac 1 \pi$, $b=\frac 1 e$, $c=\gamma$. This would give, as an estimate, $x=1.25923$ while the "exact" solution given by Newton method is $1.28486$.

We could do better at the price of more terms and very lond expressions. But, starting from this guess, Newton method would work like a charm.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.259229442 \\
 1 & 1.284569396 \\
 2 & 1.284861903 \\
 3 & 1.284861941
\end{array}
\right)$$